# Why does my code not work in windows terminal but does in others? (Python)

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm, windows-10, pynput

Ok so I am making an autoclicker, and all works great so far - kinda. It works perfectly in PyCharm terminal, and IDLE, but when double-clicking on the .py file, it opens windows terminal as expected, but only clicks once. Upon clicking any key on my keyboard, it then continues and stops in the same place, then I must click a key on my keyboard before it starts again, and it continues doing this. I used pyinstaller to convert to an exe, and converts fine but when I run it, it doesn't work at all. Someone please help with this.

```
import time
mouse = Controller()

clicker_on_query = True
clicker_time_interval = 1

while clicker_on_query == True:
    print('loop activated')
    mouse.press(Button.left)
    mouse.release(Button.left)
    print('1')
    time.sleep(clicker_time_interval)
    print('loop end')
```

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I realized that this happens only when you run the script in command prompt, while using PowerShell there seems to be no issues at all.
You can try using this piece of code which is kind of more advanced using a class and featuring start/stop keys and maybe experiment a bit more.

By the way, this seems to work on prompt as well.

```
import time
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode


delay = 1.00
button = Button.left
start_stop_key = KeyCode(char='s')
exit_key = KeyCode(char='e')


class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False

    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                mouse.click(self.button)
                time.sleep(self.delay)
            time.sleep(0.1)


mouse = Controller()
click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
click_thread.start()


def on_press(key):
    if key == start_stop_key:
        if click_thread.running:
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
        else:
            click_thread.start_clicking()
    elif key == exit_key:
        click_thread.exit()
        listener.stop()


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

credits for the code: https://nitratine.net/blog/post/python-auto-clicker/